# How to create a technical indicator in quantmod package

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm a newbie to R and I am facing some problems with the creation of a technical indicator. More specifically, I want to create an indicator, `Fibonacci`, which will be added to the `chartSeries` and will consist of 5 horizontal lines. The data I am working with are the closing  prices of a stock. So the graph I want to create will have one horizontal line in the point of the max closing price, one horizontal line in the point of the min closing price and three horizontal lines between the previous two. The code I wrote in order to take the five values of a time series of closing prices of a stock is the following:

```
Fibonacci <- function(x) {
x <- try.xts(x, error = as.matrix)
n <- nrow(x)
min <- runMin(x,n=n)
max <- runMax(x,n=n)
high <- 0.62*(max-min) + min
middle <- 0.5*(max-min) + min
low <- 0.38*(max-min) + min
res <-cbind(na.spline(min),na.spline(max),na.spline(high),
            na.spline(middle),na.spline(low))
colnames(res)<- c("min","max","high","middle","low") 
reclass (res, x)
}
```

I also wrote the following code in order to add the technical indicator to the existing `chartSeries` plot of `quantmod` package :

```
addFibonacci<- function(col = "red",overlay = TRUE){
stopifnot("package:TTR" %in% search() || require("TTR", quietly = TRUE))
lchob <- quantmod:::get.current.chob() 
x <- as.matrix(lchob@xdata)
chobTA <- new("chobTA")
chobTA@new <- !overlay
if (!is.OHLC(x)) 
    stop("Fibonacci requires HL series")
else {
fibon <- Fibonacci(Cl(x))
}
chobTA@TA.values <- fibon[lchob@xsubset]
chobTA@call <- match.call()
chobTA@on <- 1
chobTA@params <- list(xrange = lchob@xrange, colors = lchob@colors, 
    color.vol = lchob@color.vol, multi.col = lchob@multi.col, 
    spacing = lchob@spacing, width = lchob@width, bp = lchob@bp, 
    x.labels = lchob@x.labels, time.scale = lchob@time.scale, 
    col = col)
if (is.null(sys.call(-1))) {
    TA <- lchob@passed.args$TA
    lchob@passed.args$TA <- c(TA, chobTA)
    lchob@windows <- lchob@windows + ifelse(chobTA@new, 1, 
        0)
    chartSeries.chob <- quantmod:::chartSeries.chob
    do.call(chartSeries.chob, list(lchob))
    invisible(chobTA)
}
else {
    return(chobTA)
}
}
```

The problem is that the indicator is not getting added to the chart and I am also getting the following error message:

```
Error in do.call(x@passed.args$TA[[j]]@name, list(x@passed.args$TA[[j]])) :
  'what' must be a character string or a function
```

Any ideas for what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than writing the `add*` function from scratch, you could just use `newTA`:

```
> library(quantmod)
> getSymbols("AAPL")
[1] "AAPL"
> addFibonacci <- newTA(Fibonacci,on=1)
> chartSeries(AAPL, TA="addFibonacci()")
Error in addFibonacci() : could not find function "get.current.chob"
```

Hmm, apparently `get.current.chob` isn't exported... that's okay, we can just change the function ourselves.  After calling `addFibonacci <- newTA(Fibonacci,on=1)`, `addFibonacci` is defined as:

```
addFibonacci <- function (..., on = 1, legend = "auto") 
{
    #lchob <- get.current.chob()
    lchob <- quantmod:::get.current.chob()
    x <- as.matrix(lchob@xdata)
    x <- Fibonacci(x = x)
    yrange <- NULL
    chobTA <- new("chobTA")
    if (NCOL(x) == 1) {
        chobTA@TA.values <- x[lchob@xsubset]
    }
    else chobTA@TA.values <- x[lchob@xsubset, ]
    chobTA@name <- "chartTA"
    if (any(is.na(on))) {
        chobTA@new <- TRUE
    }
    else {
        chobTA@new <- FALSE
        chobTA@on <- on
    }
    chobTA@call <- match.call()
    legend.name <- gsub("^add", "", deparse(match.call()))
    gpars <- c(list(...), list())[unique(names(c(list(), list(...))))]
    chobTA@params <- list(xrange = lchob@xrange, yrange = yrange, 
        colors = lchob@colors, color.vol = lchob@color.vol, multi.col = lchob@multi.col, 
        spacing = lchob@spacing, width = lchob@width, bp = lchob@bp, 
        x.labels = lchob@x.labels, time.scale = lchob@time.scale, 
        isLogical = is.logical(x), legend = legend, legend.name = legend.name, 
        pars = list(gpars))
    if (is.null(sys.call(-1))) {
        TA <- lchob@passed.args$TA
        lchob@passed.args$TA <- c(TA, chobTA)
        lchob@windows <- lchob@windows + ifelse(chobTA@new, 1, 
            0)
        chartSeries.chob <- chartSeries.chob
        do.call("chartSeries.chob", list(lchob))
        invisible(chobTA)
    }
    else {
        return(chobTA)
    }
}
```

And you can see where I replaced the call to `get.current.chob()` with `quantmod:::get.current.chob()`.  Now it should work.

```
chartSeries(AAPL, TA="addFibonacci()")
```

Success!

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and the help. I didn't know that i could use the newTA function. I am just wondering why i can't simply call the addFibonacci() and take the plot i want, like all the addTA functions, and instead i have to call the chartSeries function? For example when i call the addFibonacci i take :Error in addFibonacci() : object 'chartSeries.chob' not found